# Grab the last insert id from one table to put into another table

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement, shopping-cart

probably a simple one for you developers out there

I have this code to insert an order_id and order_name into the 'orders' table:

```
<?php
// start the session handler
require_once('dbfunction.php');

//connect to database
$conn = DB();

require_once('header.php');

//should we process the order?
if (isset($_POST['process'])) {

$order_name = $_POST['order_name'];

//create initial order
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (order_name) VALUES (?)");

//bind the parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $order_name);

    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
```

I now want to insert the order items into the order_items table and I cant seem to keep that same ID that was created when inserting into the 'orders' table and add it to the 'order_items' table along with the order_items. Here is my code:

```
//this gets the most recent auto incremented ID from the database - this is the order_id we have just created
$order_id = mysql_insert_id();

//loop over all of our order items and add to the database
foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $item) {

  $prod_id = $item['prod_id'];
  $quantity = $item['quantity'];
  $prod_type = $item['prod_type'];

  $stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO order_items (order_id, prod_id, quantity, prod_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

  //bind the parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('iiis', $order_id, $prod_id, $quantity, $prod_type);

    // Execute query
    $stmt->execute();
}

    echo "<p class='black'>Order Processed</p>";
```

Comment: sqli with prepared statements

Comment: That looks great, whats wrong with it? (Question?)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: VERSION MYSQLi if that is a version :s

Comment: I worked out that this is how you do it:       $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn2);

    Thanks for the inspiration guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it's because whatever database library you are using is doing something to invalidate the `mysql_insert_id` (assuming it's even using the `mysql` functions). I'd suggest you look into the library to find out what method they suggest you use instead.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has @@IDENTITY

It looks like mySQL has LAST_INSERT_ID();

My guess is you are using mySQL. If not, then please let me know the version so I can update